# Reducing an ODE using differential Invariants

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, lie-algebras

In solving ODEs through symmetry methods, we find the symmetries and use them to determine differential invariants.
We can then use these differential invariants to reduce the order of the ODE and hence make it easier to solve.

The ODE given is:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = w\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{2}{y}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2
$$

The differential invariants are : $r = y$ and $v = e^{wt}[1+\frac{wy}{y'}]$

When we determine $\frac{dv}{dr}$ and sub-in the ODE, we get:
$$
\frac{dv}{dr} = 0
$$

The paper I am looking at solves this as:
$$
y(t)=\frac{a}{b-e^{wt}}
$$

This is what I get:
\begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dr} & = 0\\
v & = a\\
e^{wt}[1+\frac{wy}{y'}] &= a\\
1 + \frac{wy}{y'} &= ae^{-wt}\\
wy &= y'\left(ae^{-wt}-1\right)\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= \frac{wy}{ae^{-wt}-1}\\
\frac{dy}{y} &= dt\frac{w}{ae^{-wt}-1}\\
\ln y &= -\ln(e^{wt}-a) + \ln b\\
y &= \frac{b}{e^{wt}-a}\\
 \end{align}

Is this correct?

Comment: How did $y'$ become $y$ in the last set of equations?

Comment: You are absolutely right @Chrystomath I need to fix that. Now I am back to trying to get the solution that was given ...